# Mongoose get the size of the relations from one collection to another

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `Categories` collection. And another `Videos` collection. Each video belongs to a category.

I want to list out all the categories, along with the number of videos in that category.
I am using aggregate to join the two, and fetch the required fields in category collection. From the videos collection I need only the amount of videos corresponding to the collection.

How can use aggregate to fetch the size of the total videos relation?

Or is there any thing that I am missing?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
The relation is basically, in each video there is `category_id` that corresponds to the category

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to this,
you could use `aggregate` along with `lookup` and `project` to get the results

```
await this.categories
            .aggregate([
                {
                    $match: filter,
                },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: 'resources',
                        localField: '_id',
                        foreignField: '_category_id',
                        as: 'videos',
                    },
                },
                {
                    $project: {
                        name: '$name',
                        count: { $size: '$videos' },
                    },
                },
            ])
```